# Django rating system

Tags: python, django, rating

I am trying to implement a rating system on a Django website.
I have done my rating with just one star (booleanfield) false/true :

```
<!-- Favorite Album -->
<a href="{% url 'music:favorite_album' album.id %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-favorite" role="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star {% if album.is_favorite %}active{% endif %}"></span>
</a>
```

and this these are my album model :

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So, I want to know how to change this rating, so I will be able to select from 1 to 5 (in numbers) to rate the album. And by that, the album model should look like this I think :

```
..........
        is_favorite = models.IntegerField()
..........
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
Rating_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Poor'),
    (2, 'Average'),
    (3, 'Good'),
    (4, 'Very Good'),
    (5, 'Excellent')
)

is_favorite = models.IntegerField(choices=Rating_CHOICES, default=1)
```

Comment: In `Album model` above `is_favorite`

Comment: but how can I use it in the index page for example, like the first code :

<!-- Favorite Album -->
<a href="{% url 'music:favorite_album' album.id %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-favorite" role="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star {% if album.is_favorite %}active{% endif %}"></span>
</a>

Comment: You can do it using forms. But making favorite and ratings are 2 different things. You need to decide on that.

Comment: I first wanted to do favorites, but then I wanted to do ratings, so I know I need to change the index code as well

Comment: Thats what I said by using above you can implement ratings in the easiest way.

Comment: Please select the answer if it helped your cause. Thanks for all the cooperation.